# Confusión implementando una billetera virtual via REST en PHP

Tags: php, rest

¿Qué es este path?

```
$duplo = new \Duplo\DuploClient
```

Se supone que me debería dar un archivo php o como se interpreta eso?

El link de referencia es este https://developers.tryduplo.com/doc/wallets-create-a-wallet,
no logro entender como se usa, alguien podría aclararme un poco?

Comment: Eso es la forma de instanciar un Objeto DuploClient a partir de la Clase DuploClient del package Duplo. No es sólo la documentación de Duplo la que debes comprender, sino una repasada al lenguaje (PHP). No lo tomes a mal, es un comentario amistoso. Saludos

Comment: uso php, pero esto casi nunca lo uso, se que es instanciar, pero la gran duda es: ¿como se instancia eso, sino no hay una clase php o algo que el proveedor me diera? ese es mi problema, tengo esa URL , ese ejemplo pero eso no me dice nada..........

Comment: Supongo que en algún momento instalas la dependencia o librería de Duplo en tu entorno. Usas Laravel o algún otro Framework? La *ruta* no es más que la forma de usar dicha librería. Saludos

Comment: PHP puro, nada de frameworks

Comment: Con mayor razón, seguramente no has instalado la dependencia de Duplo. En la página de inicio habla de SDK, te hará falta registrarte y descargar el SDK para PHP: *Find out what you can build with Duplo’s API through our
documentation, __SDKs__ and sample use cases.*

Comment: estoy registrado porque sino no me daban la API-KEY, ese SDK del que habla la pagina lleva al ejemplo que justamente no entiendo, bueno, veré que hago sino lo hará otro ........., Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Qué es este path? $duplo = new \Duplo\DuploClient

Con esa linea de codigo, se instancía un objeto de la clase DuploClient. Para saber utilizarlo a partir de ahí habría que leer la documentación del package y de PHP ya que tu pregunta es muy abierta dependiendo del uso que se le vaya a dar.

Comment: Entiendo, pero eso es toda la documentación, por eso que ando tan perdido, es como que no tiene sentido lo que ponen ahi. como siempre veo cosas asi y muy pocas veces un archivo php para bajar (que seria la clase) entonces no entiendo que tipo de ejemplo es eso.